# Passing peripheral objects to be used as class members in embedded systems

Tags: c++, embedded, mbed

When doing embedded programming in C++ (say, with MBED), I very frequently have globally declared objects for device peripherals like I2C or Serial, which typically take parameters for the pins you're using for that device for your specific application:

```
I2C i2c(SDA_1, SCL_1);
Serial my_serial(D7, D8);
```

How do I correctly pass these objects into other classes? I want to keep all the application specific information in my platform level code, and ideally every class in the application should be using the same instance of these objects, but I can't seem to get the constructor syntax set up properly so that a peripheral object can be passed into a class on declaration and then used as a member object within that class.

**Example:** 
I declare a device peripheral globally in my main.cpp file:

```
I2C i2c(SDA_1, SCL_1);
```

I need to use this i2c peripheral in several objects I use in my application, such as ThingController. Here's my attempt at passing these objects in with pointers:

ThingController.h

```
class ThingController {
public:
    ThingController(I2C *i2c);
    void init();
    void run();
private:
    I2C my_i2c;
```

ThingController.cpp

```
Editor::Editor(I2C *i2c)
{
    my_i2c = *i2c;
```

For this, I get "no default constructor exists for class I2C" for the header file, which implies it's just trying to make a new instance of the class. If I try passing by value instead, I get the same deal.

What is the syntax for doing this? Or, am I way off in terms of how I'm thinking about this? I haven't been able to find anything else online resembling the problem I'm having, which strikes me as weird given how frequently I need to do this exact task if I want to use classes in my application. Does everyone just pass through massive lists of application specific pins and then make new instances of these hardware peripherals for every class? Or another approach?

Comment: There's really two different questions here. First, the constructor initialisation, which my answer focused on. And second, how to structure your code and design your classes in an embedded system, which @Lundin's question focused on. His answer makes some great points - +1 from me, but you'll need to do more research Find some good open source embedded projects to see how others structure their code, and learn some good design patterns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the member `my_i2c` as an *instance* of `I2C`, which means its default constructor will be called in the constructor of `ThingController` if you don't call it yourself. Since it does not have a [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/default_constructor), you're getting this error.

All you need to do is make the instance member a *reference* (or pointer) rather than a value, like this:

```
class ThingController {
public:
    ThingController(I2C& i2c);
    void init();
    void run();
private:
    I2C& my_i2c;
}

Editor::Editor(I2C& i2c) :
    my_i2c(i2c)
{
}
```

You could use a pointer rather than a reference, but in this case the semantics of a reference better suit your situation - you want to initialise it once and not change it.

It would be a good idea to read up on [constructors and member initialiser syntax](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list) which covers all this.

> Does everyone just pass through massive lists of application specific pins and then make new instances of these hardware peripherals for every class? Or another approach?

No, that would be a very bad idea. :) Peripherals such as I2C and SPI should have a singleton wrapper class, which allows you to serialise access. If you passed in the pin definitions and created multiple instances of `I2C` class (for example) you could end up having two different parts of your code trying to access the peripheral at the same time, and cause all sorts of bizarre and difficult-to-debug problems. The above approach is fine, and you would also want to look at adding a mutex and having lock/unlock methods on the I2C class.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense. Does this mean I would need to dereference for every call in my new class, however? `(&I2C).read()` I noticed I could do this with pointers, and the code will compile, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Turned out the not working part was a different piece of code. I see that no dereferencing is required for this setup. Thanks for the answer! Is this a common way of handling hardware peripherals? And what's the terminology for the the `: my_i2c(i2c)` part, a copy constructor?

Comment: There's no need to "dereference" a reference like you would a pointer. The links that I provided above explain all the above in great detail - look at initialiser lists. As for general design considerations, @Lundin's answer makes some great points. Sounds like some more research would really help. This stuff isn't easy.

Answer (score 1):

To begin with, you should not declare anything global - least of all C++ classes. This will give you all manner of initialization order bugs. The order of initialization matters a lot in most embedded systems.

What you should do, is to declare all such objects local to the main loop/application code. If several parts of your code needs to access the I2C, then you pass the object to them.

*However*, if several parts of your program needs to access raw I2C, then your design is already wrong. It is bad OO design to have some random part of your program know about hardware-specific things like "SDA_1", "SCL_1".

Only the I2C driver should speak directly to the peripheral and "know" about I2C hardware. You need to implement a HAL on top of that one. (Optionally the HAL can be an abstract base class and the driver can inherit it.) And you should only allow as many I2C object instances as there are hardware peripherals available.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on your first point? Perhaps this is a bad habit coming off of Arduino and Mbed example programs, where the full list of device peripherals is almost always declared directly before the main loop. I agree that it seems bad to pass along pin-level information, which was a motivator for my question. How do you feel about @gavinb's proposed solution?

Comment: @Hierophect Object-oriented design dictates encapsulation of data, globals are the opposite. Sure, you can declare some variables as `static` at file scope and that's often fine, but you will still have problems with [static initialization order](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/ctors#static-init-order) and thread-safety. Arduino, being a hobbyist platform, shouldn't be used as a reference for _anything_, particularly not for how to write proper C or C++ programs.